# Sed: replace a specific part

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I need to replace a specific part of a link

for example:

```
http://sub.somedomain.com/s/be2b46b4cb28ed64fe59d191cb600117/2013/image.jpg
```

to

```
http://sub.somedomain.com/s/123123/2013/image.jpg
```

what I've tried:

```
echo "http://sub.somedomain.com/s/be2b46b4cb28ed64fe59d191cb600117/2013/image.jpg" | sed "s@/s/(.+?)/@123123@g"
```

Comment: sed requires you to escape `(` and `)` to use them for grouping. But why do you need grouping if you don't have a backreference in the replacement?

Comment: Look at this:  <?php
$d = date('Y/M/D');

$a = explode('/',$d);

$b ='';
foreach($a as $d) {
 $b .= "/$d";
 echo "$b<br />";
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed "s@/s/[^/]*/@/s/123123/@g"
```

Problems with your regex:

- brackets `(` and `)` are regular characters in basic regular expressions (BRE) (and they are not really needed here)
- `+` is also not special in BRE
- if you enabled extended regexes with `sed -E`, you would match too much because you don't stop at the next slash